# multi-source monitoring companies

Tags: monitoring, routing, network-monitoring

I've mentioned before on here that I'm using Pingdom, and am quite happy with it.  For the price it's awesome.

One of the features that took us to them is that they have monitoring sites all over the world.  Our hope was that this would give us a cheap way to tell if something in our routing is b0rked, and some part of the world can't see us.  Unfortunately, they'll only alert if two different sites can't see you.

What I'm looking for is a similar monitoring system that will tell me if any individual site can't get to me.  Some logic on their side to tell the difference between me being out and them being out would be great, but I'll take it even without.

[Edit] Some clarification: I've only got one site (both logically and physically) that I want to monitor from many places.

[Edit 2] I'm happy to pay for this service.  I'm already paying Pingdom, and probably would continue to do so even with this new service, assuming that they don't have a huge overlap in what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [monitis](http://portal.monitis.com/web/guest) - they are a paid service and I haven't used them for a while, but last time I did they had monitors in multiple locations that would send you individual alerts.

Comment: My interaction with their web based sales chat (hopefully human backed, but I can't actually tell) hasn't given me too much faith in them.  We'll see.

Comment: Hmm - they are an Armenian company, so their sales communications may be a little strange.  They have some good technical people, though, and the product was pretty good when I used it.

Comment: You get the check, since it's the best answer.  I suspect I'll be going with them, though I'm not sure yet.

Answer (score 0):

apologies for the very short answer, but:

I currently have [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) configured to monitor local hosts and the ones connected via VPN.

It seems more than adequate at being able to logically deduce that if the VPN link is down, it shouldn't alert me about none responding hosts at the remote end as they're not down, but just unreachable.

The point being, that you could run monitoring at multiple locations each looking at remote locations.

This might be a step towards what you're looking for.

Comment: That could work, but it would involve having hosts in all those places, and running full Linux installs at each, just to run Nagios.  This seems like the sort of thing I can pay someone else to do, for more sites than just me :)

My concern is really that I'll have routing brain damage, and (say) Asia will think I dropped off the map.  I'd like to know about that before customers start calling.

Comment: If you ran nagios at your "home base" assuming you could connect to the box in India, then by default (or at least at a routing level) it means they can talk to you as well -otherwise you'd never receive their replies. I think.

Comment: Yeah.  But that requires me to have a box in India (and Pakistan, and Japan, and China, and and and) to test against :)

Comment: well, no, not nefariously.

Surely you can just ping the remote site? you seem to have an external service carrying that out for you at the moment.

Comment: I think we're having some confusion of terms here.  I have one site that's physically located in the US.  I want to test for connectivity to it from different parts of the world.  I can ping it, but that only tells me that wherever I'm pinging from can get to it.  Pingdom will do that from multiple locations, but won't tell me if only one can't see it.  That's what I want.